# Catching click event only in combobox's editable area

Tags: c#, winforms, drop-down-menu

I am trying to use a C# WinForms combobox in the following manner:

a) regular use: if the "Down arrow" button is pressed, the dropdown area opens and the user selects the desired item - no problem there..

b) advanced use: if the user clicks into the editable are of the dropdown control, another dialog with advanced selection mechanisms opens.

Currently, I am calling the advanced dialog in the combobox's onclick event handler. However, now the regular use of the DropDownbox is not usable any more. The advanced dialog is opend even if you click only on the dropdown arrow.

I couldn't find another likely event that I could use, so I assume that I have to check in the eventhandler if the user clicked into the control's editable part or on the control's button. Any ideas how to do that effectivly?

Thanks for all hints.

Answer (score 0):

There are two events of interest; DropDown and Click. Handle DropDown in the "normal" way. For Click, you might actually try handling MouseDown, which includes coordinates. Turn those coordinates (which are based on the cursor's position on the entire screen) into the position relative to the control, and if the mouse is currently on the arrow portion of the control, simply exit and allow the default behavior to happen. Otherwise, show the more advanced dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

I did it (not so beautiful but it works)

```
void comboBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Calculate cursor position
    Point pointCursorLocal = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);

    // Calculate rectangle of working area.
    Rectangle rectangle = this.comboBox.Bounds;
    rectangle.Size = new Size(rectangle.Size.Width - 10, rectangle.Height);

    // Check them
    if (rectangle.Contains(pointCursorLocal))
        // CLICK ON WORKING AREA ...
}
```